# Number of arrangements of A,B,C,D,E,F with conditions.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many arrangements are there of A,B,C,D,E,F if B follows immediately after A or D immediately after C or F immediately after E ?

Here is my solution:

let $A1$ be the set where B is immediately after A,

let $A2$ be the set where D is immediately after C,

let $A3$ be the set where F is immediately after E,

Then $$N(Ai) = 5!$$ $$N(AiAj) = 4!$$$$N(AiAjAk) = 3!$$

And $N(A1\bigcup A2\bigcup A3)$ = C(3,1)5! - C(3,2)4! + C(3,3)3!

Is there an easier way to do this? I tried to use a generating function, could not get it to work.

Comment: Think of $AB$ as one letter. Also the for the other cases $CD$ and $EF$.

Comment: I did use AB as one letter. 6 letter originally, then each Ai = 5!, and to avoid double counting, N(Ai,Ak), etc

Comment: It is canonical Inclusion/Exclusion, well done.

Comment: Any Idea how to form a generating function for this type of question? Its not needed but I like to check my answers with them.

Comment: Thinking of them as one letter gives $3$ letters in total. So there are $3!$ arrangements (unless I am overlooking something...) Yes I am. I read "and" in stead of "or". Sorry.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to use LaTeX? Your work is hard to follow. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @ml0105 Thanks for the link, Ive looked for it many times before.